# Retrieve dn with django-auth-ldap

Tags: python, django, ldap, django-auth-ldap

I'm writing a web app with django and an Ldap backend to authenticate users. Authentication is done, and attribute mapping is also done with django-auth-ldap (thanks ...).
But in the web interface, users need to update some informations like description, phone etc ...

So i need to retrive the dn attribute to update current user and not another. I try to map the distinguish name with and an attribute but not working...
Any ideas ?

Please find below current code.

settings.py :

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
"dn" : "ldap_user.dn",
    "name": "cn",
    "description": "description",
    "employeeType": "employeeType",
    ... }
```

but no resutls...

And i try also to write in my view :

```
def update_description(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = DescriptionUpdateForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        description = form.cleaned_data['description']
        user = request.user
        old_description = user.description
        user.description = description
        user.save()
        try:
            l = ldap.initialize(settings.AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI)
            l.simple_bind_s(settings.AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN, settings.AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD)
            user_ldap_dn = LDAPBackend().django_to_ldap_username(user.email).dn
            l.unbind_s()
        except ldap.LDAPError, e:
            print e
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/profile')
else:
    form = DescriptionUpdateForm()

return render(request, 'edit_description.html', {'form': form,})
```

But no result, i can't retrive the dn entry for this user...

Thanks in advance, 
Loic.

Answer (score 0):

The distinguished name (or primary key) is always returned from an LDAP search operation for each entry that matches the search parameters. The distinguished name is not an attribute.

Comment: Yes, for each ldap request, distinguished name has been return, but i use django-auth-ldap to authenticate users.
And i need to store distinguished name in one attribute to limit the number of ldap request ...
So i would like to store the distinguished name on mysqldb, and then retrive this information like another attributes.